# Opera Extension - persona.ini

Tags: opera-extension

I am uploading my first Opera Extension.  It is very simple.  It is a toolbar button that launches a popup window.  It works perfectly fine in Opera developer mode.  Opera is not letting me upload it successfully.  It keeps saying the persona.ini file is missing.  Meanwhile I downloaded quite a few extensions already live in the Opera Extensions Directory to see their persona.ini files and none of them even have a persona.ini file.  I can only find one example of a persona.ini file online and it must not be correct because it doesn't allow the upload either.

Has anyone experienced this?  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10):

You're probably uploading the extension in .zip format, which is not supported — only .crx and .nex are supported. .zip is only used for Opera themes (hence the reference to persona.ini).

So, to fix this, you can do the following: when in developer mode, use the "Pack extension" button to pack and sign your extension. Then try uploading it again — everything should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully uploaded zip package in Opera store.

I faced with same issue ("persona.ini is missed") when tried to upload zip package with root folder  - I mean zip content: "Sources/content (like manifest.json). 
Chrome store accepted this package but for Opera you could try to create zip package with all content without parent folder (Sources folder in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Opera doesn't support till now the `.zip` file you need to upload either `.nex` or `.crx` file.
To create a `.nex` file..

1. In your opera URL,just type `opera://extensions`
2. Click on Pack Extensions.
3. Browse to the root directory of your extension and click on okay.

The file will also create an `.pem` file along with `.nex` file. Keep your pem file safe and with you for uploading/upgrading your extension.

Answer (score 0):

I Followed All these Steps and it works 100%

In your opera URL, just type opera://extensions
Click on Pack Extensions.
Browse to the root directory of your extension and click on okay.
The file will also create an .pem file along with .nex file. Keep your pem file safe and with you for uploading/upgrading your extension.